# What does this php code means

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Hello I am new to PHP and I don't know exactaly what does this code means

```
$de = array('Ä'=>'ae','ä'=>'ae','Ü'=>'ue','ü'=>'ue', 'Ö'=>'oe', 'ö'=>'oe', 'ß'=>'ss');
 strtr($str, ${$de});
```

The only thing that I need to know is what does **`${$de}`** mean?

Comment: can "variable variables" contain an array?

Comment: What does it actually do? I would have thought that this should be written as 'strtr($str, $de)' - I'd expect the indirection to cause a warning and the code to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), one of the most intriguing part of the php implementation.

Sometimes usefull, always confusing:

```
$Bar = "a";
$Foo = "Bar";
$World = "Foo";
$Hello = "World";
$a = "Hello";

$a; //Returns Hello
$$a; //Returns World
$$$a; //Returns Foo
$$$$a; //Returns Bar
$$$$$a; //Returns a
$$$$$$a; //Returns Hello
$$$$$$$a; //Returns World
....
```

Comment: "confusing" is a nice way to put it... but since `$de` is an array, what in heck happens?

Answer (score 1):

That's a variable variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

Known as `Variables Variable`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php